# Estimating of unknown parameters using the method of moments

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$ be the results of $n$ independent repeated observations on random value $\xi$, which density function:

$f(x, \theta) = pf_1(x,\theta)+(1-p)f_2(x, \theta)$,

where $f_1(x, \theta) = \frac{1}{\theta}, 0 < x < \theta$,

$f_2(x, \theta) = \frac{1}{1-\theta}, \theta < x < 1$

$p, \theta$ - unknown parameters ($ 0 <= p <= 1 $)

Find estimates of unknown parameters using method of moments.

I can find first moment, expectancy,
$M\xi = \int xf(x)dx = \int_{0}^{\theta}px\frac{1}{\theta}dx + \int_{\theta}^{1}(1-p)\frac{1}{1-\theta}xdx = p\theta/2 + \frac{1-p}{2(1-\theta)}(1-\theta^2)$

and say that is equal to $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i$

But I don't see how to estimate it without numbers.

Comment: A couple of points: (a) with two unknown parameters you are going to want to use at least two moments to get two simultaneous equations to solve; and (b) your $p\theta/2 + \frac{1-p}{2(1-\theta)}(1-\theta^2)$ might be simpler written as $ \frac12(1-p +\theta)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

$$\frac{p\theta}2+ \frac{1-p}{2}(1+\theta) = \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$$
$$ \frac{1-p}{2}+\frac{\theta}2 = \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$$

We obtain a linear relationship between $p$ and $\theta$.

$$1-p = \frac{2}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i - \theta$$

That is not sufficient, you still have to find the second moment.

$$\frac{p\theta^2}3 + \frac{1-p}{3(1-\theta)}(1-\theta^3)=\frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2$$

$$\frac{p\theta^2}3 + \frac{1-p}{3}(1+\theta + \theta^2)=\frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2$$

$$ \frac{1-p}{3}(1+\theta) +\frac{\theta^2}3=\frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2$$

$$ (1-p)(1+\theta) +\theta^2=\frac3n \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2$$

$$\left( \frac{2}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i - \theta\right) (1+\theta) + \theta^2 = \frac3n \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2$$

$$\frac{2}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i  + \theta \left(  \frac{2}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i - 1\right)= \frac3n \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2$$

Now, hopefully you can solve for $\theta$ and $p$.